# How to generate unique ETH deposit address for ecommerce or payment processor?

Tags: addresses, payments

Example of a payment processor or an ecommerce website.

I would like to generate unique ETH address for each transaction.

I'm genuinely curious what is the the best way of doing it?

#### Potential solution

Generate 10000 addresses from a mnemonic, keep them on the backend. Front-end making API call to fetch a new one.

Screenshot from "Mastering Bitcoin" by Andreas:

[image]

You can assume I'll be able to sweep addresses when the gas prices are low.

#### Or maybe there is a better option?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use CREATE2 opcode to assign a wallet for each customer. These contracts can forward any payment to a central wallet. Those contract don't have to be deployed before they are used.

Some links with more details and use cases

- [Wisps: The Magical World of Create2](https://blog.ricmoo.com/wisps-the-magical-world-of-create2-5c2177027604)
- [Using non-custodial smart contracts to process ERC20 payments at scale](https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0)